# Find the next value of this number series

Tags: number-sequence

I have tried to solve few number series problems but this one is little difficult for me to solve. kindly help me to solve this.

```
-1,35,143,323,?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm.. Maybe the first number should be $6$ instead of $-1$?

Comment: This looks like this puzzle may have been taken from somewhere (v.s. one you created) - if so please provide attribution to the source. And welcome to Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I got this:

> 0*0 -1 = -1
>  6*6 -1 = 35
>  12*12-1 = 143
>  18*18 -1 = 323
>  24*24 -1 = 575

or:

> (6*0)^2 -1 = -1
>  (6*1)^2 -1 = 35
>  (6*2)^2-1 = 143
>  (6*3)^2 -1 = 323
>  (6*4)^2 -1 = 575

Comment: Or Maybe there is a Shorter way that im missing

Comment: My comment might be confusing after the edit so I removed it, but +1 from me now

Comment: Or (-1)x1, 5x7, 11x13, 17x19, 23x25, ...

Comment: @OHO That's neat. It holds true in math that $x^2 = (x + y)(x - y) + y^2$. In this instance $y$ is just 1 in every case; so it's the same equation, just a different representation. You may have known that already, just thought it was interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Bedi’s got the idea. Another way to write it would be:

> (6n)^2 - 1 where n goes from 0 to 4

So, the next number is

> (6*4)^2 - 1 = **575**